# error "xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 6" after after raining "ionic cordova build ios --prod"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

After finishing the coding of the application, I did run this code to build the ios application :
« ionic cordova build iOS —prod —release »

and i had this error:

```
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/boxcom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Scard- 
aytkzlhzyxtsgubqlplxknwhxskx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug- 
iphonesimulator/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWebViewEngine.o 
Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVWebViewEngine/CDVWebViewEngine.m normal x86_64 
objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova. 
cordova build ios exited with exit code 65.  
Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Ps: i'm using xcode version 9.2

any help would be well appreciated

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why are you using a version of Xcode which is more than 4 years out of date?